# How to use R Shiny reactive server objects in UI input widgets

Tags: r, input, shiny, reactive

I'm trying to have a Shiny app, that is connecting to a database, but the IP and so an can be modified by a User.

In short, I kind of just want to know, if its possible to have a shiny app, with objects from reactiv server parts included in the UI select inputs.

Like this:

```
library(shiny)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
    
  selectizeInput(inputId = 'inSelect',
                 label = "countries",
                 choices = getTable(),
                 multiple = TRUE,
                 options = list(maxItems = 4, 
                                placeholder = 'select up to 4 countries')
                 )
 )

server <- function(input, output) {
 
  getTable <- reactive({
    
    country <- data.frame(name=c("Germany","France","Japan"),
                          code=c("DEU","FRA","JPN"))
    countryN <- country$code
    names(countryN) <- country$name
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

when it works, it should look like this:

[image]

I know, that I can achieve this effect, by just building the DF before the UI, but my real problem is ab bit more complicated:

I want the user to type in IP, Username,PW, and DB name, to connect to the DB.
After a button click, the connection should be established and the df. country should be pulled out of the DB, not constructed.
I think, that I have to do this part in the (reactive) Server part, because I am using Input$x in the DB connection.

I hope, that my vision is somehow possible and you guys can help me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `updateSelectInput()` to update a select input from the server side of the app more info found here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/updateSelectInput.html

in your specific example you can achieve this by:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    selectizeInput(inputId = 'inSelect',
                   label = "countries",
                   choices = NA,
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(maxItems = 4, 
                                  placeholder = 'select up to 4 countries')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    getTable <- reactive({
        
        country <- data.frame(name=c("Germany","France","Japan"),
                              code=c("DEU","FRA","JPN"))
        countryN <- country$code
        names(countryN) <- country$name
        
        return(country)
    })
    
    observe({updateSelectInput(session, inputId="inSelect", label = NULL, choices = getTable()$name,
                      selected = NULL)})
    
    
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

by adding the argument `session` to the server function and then using the `updateSelectInput()` function, this must be wrapped in a reactive expression in this example I used `observe()`